# Swiftui Firebase NowPlayable Audio AVPlayerItem. Cannot Convert value of type 'StorageReference' to expected argument type 'URL'

Tags: firebase, audio, swiftui, stream, avplayer

I can't seem to figure out how to make my streamable audio through firebase a Now Playable App in Xcode 12 with SwiftUI.
Here's my code. I asked Apple for their help and they gave me a sample using m4a audio internally kept within the app. I'm using Firebase to stream the audio, cover art, receive song title and artist info in real time. I'm just trying to figure out how to make it Now Playable with the least amount of code. The code works for url and audio stored within the app but it doesn't work by being streamed with Firebase. All of the info, audio and art is uploaded in Firebase and displayed in real time so I can upload new music instantly without updating the app on the App Store. I only know how to code in SwiftUI.

```
        import AVFoundation
        import MediaPlayer
        import Firebase

// Static metadata about each song.

struct Album: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable, Hashable {

    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var image: String
    var artist: String
    var songs : [Song]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case image
        case artist
        case songs
    }
}

struct Song: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable, Hashable {

var id = UUID()
var name : String
var image: String
var artist: String
var time: String
var file: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case image
        case artist
        case time
        case file
    }
}

struct datatype: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {

    var id : String
    var image : String
}

struct DynamicMetadata {
    var playerState: PlayerState
    var playerRate: Float
    var totalTime: Float
    var elapsedTime: Float
}

// Possible values of the `playerState` property.
enum PlayerState {
    case stopped
    case playing
    case paused
}

class AudioPlayer: ObservableObject {
    
    // MARK: Playback Machinery
    
    // The songs being played.
    
    private var songItems: [Song]
    
    // The player used to play individual songs.
    private var player: AVPlayer!
    
    // Index of the currently playing item.
    private var currentItemIndex = 0
    
    // The currently playing item.
    @Published private(set) var currentStaticMetadata: Song?
    
    // The current logical state of the player.
    private(set) var playerState: PlayerState = .stopped
    
    // The current playback state.
    @Published private(set) var currentDynamicMetadata: DynamicMetadata?
    
    // `true` if the current session has been interrupted by another app.
    private var isInterrupted: Bool = false
    
    // Observers of notifications and property changes.
    private var itemObserver: NSKeyValueObservation!
    private var rateObserver: NSKeyValueObservation!
    private var statusObserver: NSObjectProtocol!
    private var interruptionObserver: NSObjectProtocol!
    private var timeObserver: Any!
    
    init(metadata: [Song]) {
        songItems = metadata
    }
    
    // MARK: State Changes
    
    // Update Now Playing Info when the current item changes.
    private func handlePlayerItemChange() {
        guard playerState != .stopped else { return }
        
        // Set the Now Playing Info from static item metadata.
        let songItem = songItems[currentItemIndex]
        let nowPlayingInfoCenter = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
        var nowPlayingInfo = [String: Any]()
        
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyMediaType] = MPNowPlayingInfoMediaType.audio.rawValue
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = songItem.name
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = songItem.artist
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = songItem.name
        
        nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
        
        // And set it for the UI too.
        currentStaticMetadata = songItem
    }
    
    // Update Now Playing Info when playback rate or position changes.
    private func handlePlaybackChange() {
        guard playerState != .stopped else { return }
        
        // Find the current item.
        
        guard let currentItem = player.currentItem else { stop(); return }
        guard currentItem.status == .readyToPlay else { return }
        
        // Set the Now Playing Info from dynamic metadata.
        let playbackInfo = DynamicMetadata(playerState: playerState, playerRate: player.rate, totalTime: Float(currentItem.duration.seconds), elapsedTime: Float(currentItem.currentTime().seconds))
        let nowPlayingInfoCenter = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
        var nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo ?? [String: Any]()
        
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = playbackInfo.totalTime
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = playbackInfo.elapsedTime
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = playbackInfo.playerRate
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] = 1.0
        
        nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
        
        // And set it in the UI too.
        currentDynamicMetadata = playbackInfo
    }
    
    // Handle an audio session interruption notification.
    private func handleAudioSessionInterruption(notification: Notification) {
        
        // Retrieve the interruption type from the notification.
        
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let interruptionTypeUInt = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
            let interruptionType = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: interruptionTypeUInt) else { return }
        
        // Begin or end an interruption.
        switch interruptionType {
            
        case .began:
            isInterrupted = true

        case .ended:
            
            // When an interruption ends, determine whether playback should resume
            // automatically, and reactivate the audio session if necessary.
            
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                
                isInterrupted = false
                var shouldResume = false
                if let optionsUInt = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt,
                    AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsUInt).contains(.shouldResume) {
                    shouldResume = true
                }
                
                switch playerState {
                case .stopped:
                    break
                    
                case .playing where shouldResume:
                    player.play()
                    
                case .playing:
                    playerState = .paused
                    
                case .paused:
                    break
                }
            }
            
            // When the audio session cannot be resumed after an interruption,
            // invoke the handler with error information.
                
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Utilities
        
    private func playerItem(atIndex itemIndex: Int) -> AVPlayerItem {
            let songItem = songItems[itemIndex]
            let songURL = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: songItem.file)
            songURL.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                } else {
    
                    do {
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default)
    //                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                    }
                    catch {
                    // report for an error
                    }
    //                var player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
                    self.player = AVPlayer(url: url!) //
    //                data.player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: url!))
    //                data.player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
                    self.player.play()
    //                self.isPlaying = true
    //                self.showcontrols = true
    //                audioPlayer.playPauseTrack()
                }
            }
            return AVPlayerItem(url: songURL)
        }
```

Comment: You've shared quite a bit of code, and I didn't read all of it to see where exactly the error occurs (hint: you might want to read about [creating a minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). But from the error message it seems like you need to [download the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_files) from the file, or [get a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url) in order to play it.

Comment: Thank you. I shorten the code a bit more. I really appreciate your help. Hopefully this helps understand what I'm having an issue with.

Comment: @Frank I appreciate your answer but it did not help me compile successfully. Apple is being very vague when I ask them.

Comment: I am not seeing any Firebase code that downloads the file either to memory or to disk. Also the error in your question title is accurate; a reference to a space in storage is not the same thing as a URL. Also, there is just way too much code for us to parse through; 230 lines is about  200 lines too many. Please narrow it down to the code you're using to download the file and ensure the [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) allow said data to be read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error comes from here:

```
return AVPlayerItem(url: songURL)
```

You've declared `songURL` as `let songURL = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: songItem.file)`, meaning that it is a `StorageReference`, which `AVPlayerItem` can't deal with.

The problem is that you can't return something valid there, as the download URL hasn't been loaded yet. I'm not sure what `AVPlayerItem` does, but you might want to see if you can construct it later - in the callback, where you already do `self.player = AVPlayer(url: url!)`.